# Array push to multi dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm new to php and arrays. I have an array named $get which contains:

```
array (size=5)
0           => 
array (size =3)
'name'    => string '6Jj3sHDG2Dciq92P0fELyw==' (length                    =24)
'email'   => string 'uYyYxVif7yOSO+nxLXRoKxj8oulFOp9EONDvMXC+zE8=' (length=44)
'password'=> string 'umxCWS0OXGTomcDWkHZUCA==' (length                    =24)

1           => 
array (size =3)
'name'    => string 'GjtDUw6NwmjQuoG/lwWYcg==' (length                    =24)
'email'   => string 'gHi5V7tzYABdlb1iCr8Tuw==' (length                    =24)
'password'=> string 'umxCWS0OXGTomcDWkHZUCA==' (length                    =24)

2           => 
array (size =3)
'name'    => string 'PB/6qLhQ/xe8iRmjWglb8g==' (length                    =24)
'email'   => string 'ZvTXUau05ubgzOEn/cY0XQ==' (length                    =24)
'password'=> string 'umxCWS0OXGTomcDWkHZUCA==' (length                    =24)

3           => 
array (size =3)
'name'    => string 'nYFzzMaZxZ7F5zV9jE7X5A==' (length                    =24)
'email'   => string '0oyJhuD9u5PHLku+wV9xhQ==' (length                    =24)
'password'=> string 'umxCWS0OXGTomcDWkHZUCA==' (length                    =24)

4           => 
array (size =3)
'name'    => string 'XEJyjRWo0jKt4XjSRct6/A==' (length                    =24)
'email'   => string 'JQyW/v9RATiJs8m9QwPRwA==' (length                    =24)
'password'=> string 'umxCWS0OXGTomcDWkHZUCA==' (length                    =24)
```

I am looping each one of them to decrypt it. How can I save it to an array or overwrite the array itself with the decrypted one? Here's how I decrypt and loop it.

```
    $get = Users::getAll();
    $decr= new Cipher("somekey");
    foreach( $get as $result )
    {
        //Decryption
        $new_decrypted_name    = $decr->decrypt($result['name']);
        $new_decrypted_email   = $decr->decrypt($result['email']);
        $new_decrypted_password= $decr->decrypt($result['password']);
    }
```

I've searched also but seems they have different implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    $get = Users::getAll();
    $decr = new Cipher("somekey");
    foreach( $get as $key => $result )
    {    
       $get[$key]['name'] = $decr->decrypt($result['name']);
       $get[$key]['email'] = $decr->decrypt($result['email']);
       $get[$key]['password'] = $decr->decrypt($result['password']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

like this you can do it dynamically

```
$decrypted = [];
 foreach ($get as $key => $result) {
  foreach ($result as $input => $value) {
    $decrypted[$key][$input]=  $decr->decrypt($value);
  }
}
```